# Dynamic Month and Year Column headers?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm working in SSRS and I'm trying to create dynamic month and year header columns to look like this: 
Oct 2015 | Nov 2015 | Dec 2015 | Jan 2016 | Feb 2016 
The code I've tried is this: 
`=MONTHNAME(Today), TRUE) & " " & YEAR(Now)`
This gives the desired result, and I know if I do +1, it'll go to the next month or year, but what happens when it turns January? How can I make sure next year's months have 2016?Is this possible? Not sure if I'm making sense on this, but I can clarify if needed. 
Basically, I have 12 columns that have the months in them, and the column names will slowly move to the left. How can I make sure the year corresponds with the correct month when the year changes?

Comment: Is it something you're looking for? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337194%28v=sql.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 You didn't specify how you're +1'ing your date.

Comment: datepart will help you

Comment: I'm adding +1 to month. Here's an update of the code for when it is greater than 12: `=MONTHNAME(IIF(MONTH(Today)+2>12,MONTH(Today)+2-12,MONTH(Today)+2), TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I found my answer. Here's my solution if anyone else needs it. What I had to do was another if statement when the month's value was greater than 12, add 1 to the year value. If it's not, it will default to the current year.
`=MONTHNAME(IIF(MONTH(Today)+4>12,MONTH(Today)+4-12,MONTH(Today)+4), TRUE) & " " &
IIF(MONTH(Today)+4>12,YEAR(NOW)+1,YEAR(NOW))`

Thanks for the tips guys!

Answer (score 0):

Glad you were able to figure out a way.

There's more than one way to skin a tauntaun:

```
=MONTHNAME(DATEADD("M", 4, Today()), TRUE) & " " &
YEAR(DATEADD("M", 4, Today()))
```